# iMac Target Display Mode black screen

Tags: target-display

I use an iMac with [Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) from a Macbook Pro. Sometimes when I enable Target Display Mode, the iMac screen stays black, even if my Macbook Pro's display suggests that another monitor has been plugged in (apps move away from the screen).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Posted my answer in a similar thread [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361932/296349). Hope this helps.

Comment: It's worth noting that, per the linked KB article, "Target display mode requires macOS High Sierra or earlier. It does not work with macOS Mojave or later.", and, "This article has been archived and is no longer updated by Apple".  So they retroactively removed this feature, and its reliability is just going to get worse and worse over time.  It's a real bummer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Macbook, change the *rotation* on the iMac display to 90°, then revert it back (or let it revert back after the timeout) to Standard. That seems to snap it out of its zero-brightness funk <strike>more or less every time</strike> much more frequently than other display changes.[1]

(Of course, you can't do this in clamshell mode, you need some functioning display to use System Preferences→Displays on.)

[1]: (I've seen it fail once or twice, but it is the most reliable workaround I've found yet.)

Update 2021-07-12: [Apple discontinued support for Target Display Mode in all operating systems since High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592), and so it was likely that this was officially unsupported / broken even at the time the question was written. I also definitely used TDM on Mojave for a while, and I think maybe even on a Catalina beta for a while; it still *almost* worked but it was *incredibly* janky.  So if you've upgraded your iMac … some of this fiddling might help you, but it probably just won't work.

Answer (score 4):

On closer inspection, it looks like the display is not actually uniformly black. This led me to conclude that perhaps the backlight was just not turned on properly, and led me to discover the following workaround:

1. Log into the iMac
2. Change the brightness to a different level (e.g. up or down by one). The level seems to need to be different from the one previously used.
3. Enable Target Display Mode again, by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't seem to work super reliably for me.  For while it seemed like it did, but I'm trying to get TDM to kick in right now and it's just black no matter what buttons I press.

Comment: @Glyph just coming across this issue now and so far the only fix I've found is to log out of the account on the iMac so I'm at the login screen before hitting command+F2. Would be interested to hear if the same works for you

Comment: I've got the same issue these days, and it no longer works for me either. The way it failed almost seemed like it was a slow hardware death of sorts rather than a software issue, although the iMac still works fine when not in Target Display Mode.

Comment: @CupawnTae Logging out on the iMac doesn't work at all; it just doesn't recognize ⌘-F2, won't go into TDM at all on the login screen.  However, I have found *another* workaround which seems reliable: on the macbook, change the rotation to 90°, then revert it back to Standard.  That seems to snap it out of its zero-brightness funk more or less every time. (Of course, you can't do this in clamshell mode, you need *some* functioning display to use System Preferences→Displays on.)

Comment: interesting - cmd+F2 worked fine at the login screen for me, but then I updated the iMac to Catalina, and the problem either went away or is intermittent

Comment: @CupawnTae On Catalina, I've had the issue a couple of times — but on 10.15.1, I haven't seen it yet.  Maybe it's finally fixed? :)

Comment: @Glyph Maybe, fingers crossed! I've found it quite sporadic on 10.15 (haven't updated to 10.15.1 yet). It seems to happen frequently enough, but switching out of target display mode and performing pretty much any UI interaction on the iMac and then switching back to TDM seems to fix it. Also just noticed that when I tap the brightness icon in the touchbar on the macbook I now get separate sliders for the two displays - will be very interesting to see if they're both present (and working!) next time the issue occurs, particularly given the answer above.

Comment: ...which I've just managed to reproduce by pulling out the cable and reinserting it. Both sliders showed up again, and the one for the iMac display had no effect until I disabled TDM, interacted with the iMac a bit, and reenabled TDM as before.

Comment: Oh my goodness, the screen rotation workaround worked for me.

Comment: Do you want to write up that workaround as an answer?

Comment: @m01 Done. Words words words because SO has a minimum comment length.  Words.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this on another question, not sure how to link it so adding again here..
I use 2009 iMac as an external monitor to my 2015 MBP.. all running latest supported OS as of today.

COMMAND-F2 on the iMac keyboard will toggle between the running iMac local display, and the Target Display Mode (TDM) when connected to my laptop via DisplayPort. TDM always starts out at 100% brightness when you switch to it.

COMMAND-F1 will adjust brightness lower until it goes completely dark. If that happens you need to switch back to iMac local display then return again to TDM which resets to 100%

Now the important part: COMMAND-F1 sometimes doesn't respond to lower the brightness. I found this seems to happen if local iMac screen is locked.. if I switch back to local iMac display and log in to the account to unlock it, then when I switch back to TDM, the brightness control will now respond.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some luck the using the old trick of just mashing the buttons:

1. Use <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> as instructed
2. Once the failed result of the black screen of the TDM (for me iMac 2012) shows hold <kbd>Command</kbd> and press  <kbd>F2</kbd>  5 times (this should result in theory to issueing a new command for TDM On - Off - On - Off - On)
3. If this fails - try a different number of  <kbd>F2</kbd>  smashes for different results

This has proved successful for me, not sure how reliable it is though.

I am using a Macbook Pro 16 inch 2019 running Ventura, and a Late 2012 iMac running Catalina, has anyone had better luck reverting the TDM (iMac) to High Sierra (as apple advise)? I feel like Catalina on the iMac might be causing problems but I'm hesitant to restore it to High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Had to uncheck 'Automatically adjust brightness' on the iMac's display control.

Comment: I hoped the fix would be this easy, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

So for those of you who still have this problem and nothing above helps.

It only worked for me only after logging the user out on the iMac.

1. You log off
2. Press CMD + F2 (sometimes you need try it two times)

But logging off the user every time I want to use the imac in a target display mode is quite annoying. I found another option which works for me:

1. Lock iMac (CMD + CTRL + Q)
2. On the login screen of the imac click: "Switch users"
3. The list of users should appear on the screen of the iMac
4. Now press CMD + F2
5. It usually does not work from the first try. So if the screen of the iMac is just black, press CMD + F2 to exit "target screen". And then press CMD + F2 once again. Always works for me from the second try and does not require a user to be logged off from the imac.

Hope this helps